# Custom CursorAdapter give an error "The specified child already has a parent" while adding AChartEngine graph

Tags: android, android-listview, achartengine, android-cursoradapter

I have been looking around to solve this issue for a number of days now and I have seen several questions on here, some of which had been solved but none of those actually helped me as my situation is a little bit different from the rest.

In a part of my app, I'm going to show the history of all the campaigns that have started in the other part of the app. For that I'm using a listview within my history activity. here is a the code for the activity

**HistoryList.java**

```
public class HistoryList extends Activity {

Campaign_Db myCamp = new Campaign_Db(HistoryList.this);
Date_calc myDate = new Date_calc(HistoryList.this);
graphCreate mygraph = new graphCreate(HistoryList.this);

 ListView historylist;
 SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
 Cursor cursor = null;
 String picadd;
 ImageView pic;
 ArrayList<Integer> array_cap = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 Integer[] arr_cap;
 int passing_id;
 String passing_date,passing_startdate;
 GraphicalView newgraph;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.historylist);


    historylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.historylistview);

    myCamp.open();
    cursor = myCamp.gethistory();
    if(cursor !=null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    int rowenddate = cursor.getColumnIndex(Campaign_Db.KEY_ROWID);
    int rowstartdate = cursor.getColumnIndex(Campaign_Db.KEY_START);

    String camp_id = cursor.getString(rowenddate);
    passing_id = Integer.valueOf(camp_id);
    passing_date = cursor.getString(rowstartdate);
    }
    getdata();
    newgraph = mygraph.startgraph(arr_cap,this);



    HistoryAdapter histAdap = new HistoryAdapter(HistoryList.this,cursor,R.layout.historyrow,arr_cap, newgraph);


    historylist.setAdapter(histAdap);
}


private void getdata() {



String dt = myDate.Calc(passing_date);

int d = Integer.valueOf(dt);
    try {

        array_cap = myCamp.historygarphs(d,passing_id,passing_date);

    } catch (ParseException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
arr_cap = array_cap.toArray(new Integer[array_cap.size()]);



}


}
```

On that activity I set my listview to a custom adapter, and I pass the cursor to be used and also the AChartEngine graph that is to be used. The graph and the cursor data have all been tested and logged so there are no issues with them. Here is the code for the custom adapter

**HistoryAdapter.java**

```
 public class HistoryAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private Context context;
private int layout;
private Integer[] arr_cap;
String picadd;
GraphicalView newgraph;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public HistoryAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int layout, Integer[] arr, GraphicalView grp) {
    super(context, c);
    this.arr_cap= arr;
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.newgraph = grp;

}

Campaign_Db myCamp = new Campaign_Db(context);

Date_calc myDate = new Date_calc(context);

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    int rowaddress = cursor.getColumnIndex(Campaign_Db.KEY_PIC);
    int rowenddate = cursor.getColumnIndex(Campaign_Db.KEY_ROWID);
    int rowstartdate = cursor.getColumnIndex(Campaign_Db.KEY_START);
    int rowcampname = cursor.getColumnIndex(Campaign_Db.KEY_NAME);

    ImageView pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.history_picture);
    TextView enddate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.history_enddate);
    TextView startdate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.history_startdate);
    TextView campaign_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.history_campaignname);
    LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.historychart); 





    lay.addView(newgraph, new LayoutParams(220, 80));



    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    picadd = cursor.getString(rowaddress);
    enddate.setText(cursor.getString(rowenddate));
    startdate.setText(cursor.getString(rowstartdate));
    campaign_name.setText(cursor.getString(rowcampname));
    }


    File imgFile = new  File(picadd);
    if(imgFile.exists()){



        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picadd);
        Bitmap reducedbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 100, 100, true);
        Bitmap rightsidebmp = getrightside(reducedbmp);
        Bitmap finalbmp = getRoundedCornerBitmap(rightsidebmp, 50);

        pic.setImageBitmap(finalbmp);


    }

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor,ViewGroup parent ) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(layout,null,false);
    bindView(v, context, cursor);
    return v;
}

public Bitmap getrightside(Bitmap bit){
    Bitmap bmp = bit;
    File f = new File(picadd);
    ExifInterface exif = null;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

    int angle = 0;

    if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
        angle = 90;
    } 
    else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
        angle = 180;
    } 
    else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
        angle = 270;
    }

    Matrix mat = new Matrix();
    mat.postRotate(angle);
    Bitmap correctBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bit , 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), mat, true);
    return correctBmp;
}

public Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int pixels) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
            .getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundPx = pixels;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
  }
 }
```

The problem happens when I try to add the achartengine graph to the my relative layout, in a way that I have already done in another activity and it has worked.

when this line is commented, the rest of the code runs perfectly.

```
lay.addView(newgraph, new LayoutParams(220, 80));
```

From what I have been reading the error that I get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

is caused when I try to use a child and give it another parent when it already has one, however in the case here the child new graph has just been initialized in the custom adapter class and when the getparent() is used, it return null.

It would be great if anyone could help figure this out, thank you in advance.

Comment: The `bindView()` method will be called for **every** `ListView` row so your code will try to add that `GraphicView` instance to each row action which will throw the exception you see. If you want a graph in each row why don't you add it it to the row layout from the start?

Comment: I have thought of that, but from what I have seen AChartEngine does not support adding the GraphicalView from the XML layout. Correct me if i'm wrong though @Luksprog

Comment: At a quick look it seems(I haven't used the library) that you can't use it in the xml layout but this is not the problem. In the `bindView()` method simply create a new instance of the `GraphicalView` and add that(passing to your HistoryAdapter the data needed by the graphical view.).